# Is there an .onion page for Google?

Tags: anonymity

Tor is awesome, but to get maximum security, you should use the .onion pages. DuckDuckGo has an [.onion version of its search site](https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/), but is there an equivalent for Google?

Comment: Google does not offer an onion address, but there’s nothing insecure about accessing https://google.com.

Comment: @Steve the OP is absolutely correct: **for maximum security** you should stay within the network aka. use only `.onion`-sites!

Comment: @DJCrashdummy I’d argue “maximum security” is somewhat meaningless if you don’t define a threat model. Onion addresses are hard to remember and to tell if they’re correct, but typing google.com is much simpler and hard to get wrong. HSTS and certificate pinning means you can be pretty sure you’re really talking with Google in either case.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is not one. However if you want to search through onion sites, services such TORCH or [ahmia.fi](http://ahmia.fi) can help.

If you want to access Google behind TOR (sites such Google ban traffics behind TOR), take a look into my article about [bypassing Google like sites behind TOT](https://mstajbakhsh.ir/socks-rocks-again/)